# Prerequisite: fetch friendlist from facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

This question may be a non-sense for you but its blast in my mind.

I have to find out my friends by a simple php call. This file is not integrated to any website just a standalone file.
For that I have downloaded PHP SDK from [Facebook PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/tree/4.0-dev/src/Facebook)
. My question is it necessary to integrate any website to facebook app. What if I want to fetch simple friend list on a simple php file. 
And I don't understand how people are using facebook.php in their code, however I didn't find any file with name of facebook.php in the SDK. And what else is required to find friend list from facebook. Specially When I dont want to integrate any website to app. As I am working on facebook api very first time, so this question may be not be as expected. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

```
    <?php

session_start();

require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;


FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('appId', 'secretkey');
// $session is only != null, when you have the session-cookie, that is set by facebook, after the user logs in
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('');
try {
    $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch (FacebookRequestException $ex) {
    // When Facebook returns an error
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
}
if (isset($session)) {
    $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me/friends');
    $response = $request->execute();
    $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
    echo 'coming here';
    echo print_r($graphObject, 1);
}else{
    echo 'Session is not creating';
}
```

Comment: what you had tried so far???

Comment: I have create an app. I am using its api id and secret key in the code  for generating friends list and its not displaying anything.

Comment: can you share the code with us so that we can fix if any issues with it??

Comment: yes give me 5 mins. 1 more thing I didnt add any website to app, so I want to know is it necessary to add website name?

Comment: no it's fine u can use localhost or 127.0.0.1....

Comment: What if I leave blank website space?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67902/discussion-between-arpit-srivastava-and-nitu-dhaka).

Comment: just a side note: you do know that you can only get the friends who authorized your app too, and not all of them? check out the changelog for more information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Comment: @luschn Can't I get the my friend list by just hitting the facebook api through a standalone php file?

Comment: no. you need to authorize the user with your app (see the facebook docs), and you will only get those friends who authorized your app too.